# Padding Encrypted result string

Tags: encryption, padding

There is a requirement in my new job regarding encryption. We need encrypt specific data from DB and then decrypt it whenever needed. We're planning to go for DBMS_CRYPTO with AES algorithm. Now the requirement is that whatever the input string may be and whatever be its length, my encrypted string's length should be same everytime i do the encryption. For example, a 15 character string should have the length of its encrypted string same as a 24 character string. Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: That sounds extremely insecure, there is a reason why we have padding schemes.

Comment: Sorry if my doubt is silly as i'm very new to encryption. Why do you say that's extremely insecure? is there any way to do it??

Comment: "Most modern cryptographic hash functions process messages in fixed-length blocks; all but the earliest hash functions include some sort of padding scheme. It is critical for cryptographic hash functions to employ termination schemes that prevent a hash from being vulnerable to length extension attacks." from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)